# removing all marks associated with thanks on cover page

Tags: numbering, footnotes, article, covers

I would like to remove the numbering associated with `\thanks` on my cover page. I use the following command (using `article`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\let\footnoterule\relax}{}{}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{Me \and Another Person \thanks{Some Thanks}}
\date{First Draft: A long long time ago \\ This Draft: \today}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}


\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{\huge{Cool Paper}}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I would like to remove the number next to the person as well as the number next to the footnote.

Comment: do you also want to remove the text itself?

Comment: This doesn't remove the number next to the person.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: I would like the note to say "Some Thanks" with no mark to its left. I would also like there to be no mark next to Another Person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it; just use the patch for redefining `\thefootnote` to do nothing. I've reduced the MWE to a real MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\let\footnoterule\relax}{\def\thefootnote{}}{}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\author{Me \and Another Person\thanks{Some Thanks}}
\date{First Draft: A long long time ago \\ This Draft: \today}
\title{\textbf{\huge{Cool Paper}}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```